# Indy sends params with GET after POST redirect

Tags: delphi, redirect, indy, delphi-xe5, indy10

Using Delphi XE5 + Indy 10.

I am sending POST with login and password to log in. Site responds with redirect (302) to target page. In browser, redirect is handled by GET and everything goes right, but Indy continues with POST.

I solve this by using this code inside my OnRedirect handler:

```
procedure TForm1.MyRedirect(Sender: TObject;
                            var dest: string;
                            var NumRedirect: Integer;
                            var Handled: Boolean;
                            var VMethod: string);
var
  TempHttp: TIdHttp;
begin
  TempHttp := (Sender as TIdHTTP);

  if (TempHttp.ResponseCode = 302) then
    VMethod := 'GET';

  Handled := true;
end;
```

Request method is then changed to GET, but Indy still sends POST request params with GET. So I get 413 Request Entity Too Large response.

How can I make Indy NOT send params with GET after redirect? Solution inside OnRedirect would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client behavior for handling the HTTP `302` reply code is ambiguous, and often treated erroneously by various clients.  This is well documented in various RFCs, including 2068 and 2616.  The `303` reply code was created to resolve the ambiguity, but many clients still do not support `303` yet, and many servers still use `302` expecting clients to behave as if `303` was used.

`TIdHTTP` has jumped back and forth many times over the years trying to figure out what behavior should be used when `302` is received - should it redirect using `GET`, or should it redirect using `POST`?  In 2012, an `hoTreat302Like303` flag was added to the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property to let users decide what to do.  So make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy.

If `303` is received, `TIdHTTP` will clear its `Request.Source` property (thus ignoring any previous `POST` params) and send a `GET` request, ignoring the method returned by the `OnRedirect` event handler, if assigned.

If `302` is received:

1. if `hoTreat302Like303` is enabled, `TIdHTTP` will clear its `Request.Source` property (thus ignoring any previous `POST` params) and send a `GET` request, ignoring the method returned by the `OnRedirect` event handler, if assigned.
2. if `hoTreat302Like303` is disabled (which it is by default), `TIdHTTP` will send a request using the method returned by the `OnRedirect` event handler if assigned, otherwise it will send a request using the same method as the previous request that was redirected.  But in either case, it does not clear its `Request.Source` property (thus any previous `POST` params will be re-sent).  So if you change the method in the `OnRedirect` handler, you will have to update the `Request.Source` property accordingly as well, eg:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.MyRedirect(Sender: TObject;
                               var dest: string;
                               var NumRedirect: Integer;
                               var Handled: Boolean;
                               var VMethod: string);
   var
     TempHttp: TIdHttp;
   begin
     TempHttp := (Sender as TIdHTTP);

     if (TempHttp.ResponseCode = 302) then
     begin
       VMethod := 'GET';
       TempHttp.Request.Source := nil; // <-- add this
     end;

     Handled := true;
   end;
   ```